# What tools could be used for applying clustering algorithms on MovieLens?

Tags: clustering

I need to analyze the 100k MovieLens dataset for clustering with two algorithms of my choice, between the likes of k-means, agnes, diana, dbscan, and several others. What tools (like Rattle, or Weka) would be best suited to help me make some simple clustering analysis over this dataset?

Comment: Weka can be pretty slow. Try ELKI, it has very fast implementations (in particular when using indexes) and a much wider choice of algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [R](http://www.r-project.org/). [Here](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) you have a list of clustering packages available.

Answer (score 2):

Python will give you all the flexibility you need. With the NumPy and [SciPy cluster module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) you have the tools you need, and the datatypes of NumPy give you a good insight in how much memory you will use.

Comment: Why the  downvote? Is it not a good answer, or do you think it's not a good tool?

Comment: I second the python recommendation here, especially if you have trouble fitting the data set into r. If you do go the python route,  have a look at "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran

Comment: What downvote? I'm not familiar with Python yet, but it seems promising, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Victor, the first vote was a downvote (so it's now 2 upvotes/1 downvote). Maybe someone didn't like this tool. Happy I could help :)

Comment: I'll give you +1 (so that you now have your 2 original upvotes :), just because I agree that with many data points, Python may be a good option; now the minor point, IMO, is that there're not so many clustering algorithms available in SciPy compared to R.

Answer (score 1):

Python's scikit-learn library (ml library built atop numpy and scipy) is quite popular, very well documented and has several clustering algorithms as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html).

Comment: You're 3 years late.

Comment: For posterity :)

Answer (score -1):

can we use matlab for this work?I also need to cluster movielense dataset, my data is mixed of numeric and categoric dataset.
what can I do?

Comment: Hi samira, and welcome to the site! Your post seems to be a new question rather than an answer to the question. I suggest that you delete this answer and post it either as a comment. See also the [help pages](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) of this site.