# How to cluster a distance matrix?

Tags: clustering, matrix

I have a distance matrix that I want to cluster. What methods can I use to cluster the elements just based on the distance matrix (beside hierarchical clustering)?

Comment: I recommend you post clarifications as suggestions become available. What will work for you probably depends a great deal on your use case, but I understand that you might not know how to narrow the field before seeing some options.

Comment: I would like to point you to the fact that you can always obtain a cases X dimensions data from a distance matrix by multidimensional scaling.

Comment: similar question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix I vote to delete my answer since I have found similar question that already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of "distance based" clustering algorithms that can be used for any kind of similarity function (metrical or not).

For example [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and [OPTICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm), but there are literally hundreds more.