# How to reduce the dimensionality of a similarity matrix (of categorical co-occurence counts)?

Tags: clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction, hierarchical-clustering, multidimensional-scaling

Our example person `Azra` has assigned (open-ended categories of her own choosing) to a fixed set of 35 items, recorded as logical values (`TRUE`, `FALSE`).
We have summarised this data matrix into a **co-occurence matrix of items x items**, where each cell *counts the number of categories that are assigned to both items of the item-pair in question*.

We interpret these counts as a measure of *categorical similarity* between items, and consequently set the diagonal to the maximum *possible* number of categories, `18` in `Azra`'s case.
We then divide *all* cells by that maximum to scaled our cells to 1.
(We also need to do this because there are other people than `Azra` who have less then 18 categories in total, so we want to make them comparable).

Loosely speaking, we assume that our cells in this (scaled) co-occurence matrix can be interpreted as *percentages of similarity*, where 1 on the diagonal is – naturally – the maximum: item, say `but-how` with `but-how` obviously is *completely* similar.

Here's `Azra` (sorry):

```
Azra <- structure(c(1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.277777777777778, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.388888888888889, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 
0.444444444444444, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
1, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 1, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.277777777777778, 0.444444444444444, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 1, 0.277777777777778, 0.388888888888889, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.277777777777778, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.277777777777778, 1, 0.277777777777778, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.277777777777778, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.388888888888889, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.388888888888889, 
0.277777777777778, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.222222222222222, 
0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.222222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.0555555555555556, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.166666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0555555555555556, 1), .Dim = c(35L, 
35L), .Dimnames = structure(list(items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", 
"alien", "language-of-bees", "bad-hen", "correspondence", "bamboozable", 
"inventions", "gray-hair", "i-we", "the-same", "the-better", 
"cockatoo", "caravan", "comma", "headturner", "crocodile", "countries", 
"level", "morning", "idiom", "lullaby", "riddle", "eating-grandpa", 
"easter-bunny", "alphabet-of-swearing", "guilt", "trouble", "eating-animals", 
"random-poetry", "comparatively", "one-letter", "resistance", 
"conjugation", "censored"), items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", 
"alien", "language-of-bees", "bad-hen", "correspondence", "bamboozable", 
"inventions", "gray-hair", "i-we", "the-same", "the-better", 
"cockatoo", "caravan", "comma", "headturner", "crocodile", "countries", 
"level", "morning", "idiom", "lullaby", "riddle", "eating-grandpa", 
"easter-bunny", "alphabet-of-swearing", "guilt", "trouble", "eating-animals", 
"random-poetry", "comparatively", "one-letter", "resistance", 
"conjugation", "censored")), .Names = c("items", "items")))
```

A plot is easily made, but not very informative for us, because it's overwhelming, so we need some kind of summry.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = melt(Azra, varnames = c("x", "y")), mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value, )) + geom_raster() + scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "steelblue") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: Azra]

*We want to be able to see which items `Azra` thought were categorically similar, and if so, what her **dimensions** (or **clusters**?) of similarity are.*

**What would be an appropriate, and informative method to summarise this kind of data?**

Specifically, we'd like to be able to use something akin to Horn's Parallel Analysis (from a PCA context) to decide just how many retainable dimensions there *are* in `Azra`s similarity matrix.

Notes:

- We've looked at Multidimensional Scaling (MDS), but that seems to require the number of dimensions as an *input*, though to us, the number of dimensions on which `Azra` sees similarity is *an empirical* question.
- We've looked at Hierarchical Clustering Methods and respective dendrogram plots, but that seems to sit awkwardly with the fact that similarity is a multidimensional phenomenon; item `censored` might share category A with `but-how`, but category B with `language-of-bees` etc.
- We've looked at Principal Components Analysis (PCA) – mostly because we know it well, so everything starts looking like a nail ... – but that doesn't work with a similarity matrix, and even with a (converted) distance matrix [only under some conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix) about which we're not sure. (We tried anyway, see below).

---

Here's our rough, hacky and probably just plain wrong/dumb way to do this:
It doesn't give us any indication of how many dimensions we *should* be retaining.

We first make a distance matrix as per [the cosine theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix) (?!):

```
distances <- sqrt(1-Azra)
```

We then plug that into a (classical?) MDS and plot the result:

```
md_scaled <- cmdscale(d = distances)
md_scaled <- as.data.frame(md_scaled)
ggplot(data = md_scaled, mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2, label = rownames(md_scaled))) + geom_text()
```

[image: azra-mds]

Comment: I am a bit confused: can't you view your matrix as a correlation matrix? If so, you can run PCA or FA directly, without any conversions.

Comment: hehe, yes, I'm confused too, @amoeba. I initially thought that we could just treat this as a correlation matrix (since it *looks* like one, well except for the fact that it's all positive).
However, I couldn't find any source that said that it'd be ok to treat co-occurence counts as correlation matrices, and [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix) seemed to suggest that some fairly tight conditions applied.

Would you say treating it just as a correlation matrix is defensible? That would be fantastic!

Comment: You are right, it's a good point about your matrix being all positive. If two of your items were perfectly negatively correlated, you would expect to get 0 in your matrix, instead of a negative number. But this also suggests that your matrix is not really a "similarity matrix" in the sense used in the linked post.

Comment: Yes, more precisely, our matrix contains *co-occurence* **counts** (scaled to highest possible count = 1). We're assuming that the more (open-ended, `Azra`-defined) categories co-occur on some item pair, the more alike they are in her mind. 
`eating-grandpa`/ `bad-hen`, for example, share **7** categories (scaled 0.388), but `one-letter`/`conjugation` share **0** (scaled 0) categories, so we're assuming she finds the former more similar than the latter.

Is that a defensible, or at least **plausible jump from co-occurence to similarity**?

Comment: Not sure. There should be a better way. As I said, 0 co-occurences should really yield a *negative* similarity, not a zero one. Do you know what number of co-occurences you expect by chance alone? Do I understand correctly that your raw data is actually 35*18 matrix of zeroes and ones?

Comment: yes, that is correct, raw data is 35*18 of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Of these we have one for each participant (here, `Azra`, but some ~70 overall). Crucially, people have different numbers of categories, and – because they're open ended – the categories are incomparable between people, hence the need for the co-occurence matrix (or array, one matrix for each person).

Comment: @amoeba really interesting suggestion there about *negative* similarity. Do I understand you correctly that you'd suggest *centering* on what the number of co-occurences we'd expect by random chance?
I thought about that too for Horn's parallel-analysis uses, but haven't wrapped my head around how to parametrize the random draws yet.

**Do you think we *could* use PCA then?** (Values would still have to be somehow forced between 1 and -1, right?)

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your data. Why do you put 18 on the diagonal of your co-occurence matrix? If you had two identical items, they would not necessarily have all 18 trues, right? Only some categories would be assigned to them, not necessarily all 18.

Comment: uh, sorry this such a mess @amoeba. We placed 18 on the diagonal in the spirit of making this a (sort-of)-similarity matrix. 
The idea was that the that *would* be the highest possible co-occurence count.
We used this 18 on the diagonal to *scale* the other co-occurence counts (by dividing by 18).
I'm beginning to sense this was a bad idea; you're right, the diagonal item-pairs would *not* necessarily have all 18 `TRUE`s.

What would you put on the diagonal?

Comment: @amoeba thanks so much for your inspiration; I think we're up to a much better way of summarising the data now; will report back here and change the Q accordingly.

Comment: I am waiting to see what you came up with, but I think that you should be analyzing/modeling the $18\times 36$ binary data matrix itself. If the data were not binary, you could run PCA or FA on these data (i.e. construct $36\times 36$ covariance matrix). As your data are binary, you can look into approaches of doing PCA/FA with binary data (there are several). However, I think the big problem is that for 36 dimensions you only have 18 data points; this is so few that I don't think you can hope to discover much structure there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @amoeba's suggestion, we have decided to go back to the raw, logical data and conceptualize *similarity* differently, than we did in the question; we can now use the familiar (and simple) correlation coefficients and Principal Components Analysis (PCA) to summarize the data.

Instead of co-occurence *counts*, inspired by Barton's Z, we transformed the `TRUE` `FALSE` values in the logical raw data into their respective deviations from their *expected* value.
The expected value of some (inductive, participant-defined) category to be assigned `TRUE` on some item is, simply, the total number of `TRUE`s on that category, divided by the number of items.
We take these simple expected values as a weighted means of the outcomes, because draws of items (category assignments *on* items) are *independent*: just because you've assigned some `TRUE` already doesn't mean you can't assign it some more.

The resulting *deviations* from their *expected* `TRUE` value can be interpreted as a **surprisal** value of `TRUE`ishness.
For example, if some item has a positive value (close to 1), this means that it has been assigned `TRUE` despite that being *very* unlikely.
We thereby weight more heavily those cells, that are less likely to occur, and thereby carry more informational value.
We count `TRUE` as `1`, `FALSE` as `0`, and thereby conveniently get surprisal values scaled between `-1` and `1`.

We can simply find an item x item correlation matrix, where we **correlate the surprisal values of some item-pair over the observed categories**, thereby, oddly, treating categories as observations.

This yields an informative correlation matrix, where high values imply an item pair that was *surprisingly co-/non-assigned*, and a high negative value implies that of the pair, one item had high, the other a low surprisal value, that is, *surprising disagreement* about some item pair.
A low value around `0` implies, appropriately, that the item pair showed no consistent pattern across the observed categories, or that many assignments were unsurprising.

This correlation matrix is also still quite overwhelming, but can be easily reduced in dimensionality using PCA.

Here's what we did:

```
Azra <- structure(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = c(35L, 
18L), .Dimnames = structure(list(items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", 
"alien", "language-of-bees", "bad-hen", "correspondence", "bamboozable", 
"inventions", "gray-hair", "i-we", "the-same", "the-better", 
"cockatoo", "caravan", "comma", "headturner", "crocodile", "countries", 
"level", "morning", "idiom", "lullaby", "riddle", "eating-grandpa", 
"easter-bunny", "alphabet-of-swearing", "guilt", "trouble", "eating-animals", 
"random-poetry", "comparatively", "one-letter", "resistance", 
"conjugation", "censored"), categories = NULL), .Names = c("items", 
"categories")))    
# Azra has items as rownames, and (user-defined, open-eded columns as colnames), TRUE/FALSE as values

# this is the expected value
ev <- colSums(Azra) / nrow(Azra)

# and here's the surprisal value
surprise <- t(apply(X = Azra, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {x - ev}))

# now we correlate across observed CATEGORIES for every item pair
correl <- cor(t(surprise))

# and plot the result
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
ggcorr(data = correl, label = TRUE)

# and we can use PCA to summarize the overwhelming corrplot
pcares <- prcomp(x = t(surprise), retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

pcares$sdev^2 
# surprisingly, we may retain up to 8 factors which have eigenvalues > 1, though this may be overstated, and need a parallel analysis to be safe
# we know that some of the underlying surprisal value correlations might just be random chance; after all, 18 observations (categories in this case, over 35 variables is weird and not very reliable)

# we're not yet sure how to do this, but let's say we rotate Quartimax
# we preliminarily opt for Quartimax, because we like items to be *on* the axes
library(GPArotation)
rotated_Azra <- quartimax(pcares$rotation[,1:3])$loadings
# we just retain/rotate 3 PCs to be safe

g <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(x = rotated_Azra), mapping = aes(x = PC1, 
                                                                  y = PC2,
                                                                  label = rownames(rotated_Azra)))
g + geom_text()
```

[image]

[image]

There's a bunch of things we're not sure about yet, especially how to **rotate** this result, and how to appropriately deflate it (by a parallel analysis or something like that?), but that's all details.

P.S.: A fuller, though preliminary exposition with some context can be found at http://pensieve.maxheld.de/q-cat.html.
P.P.S.: The *surprisal* value is inspired by Barton's Z, full source in Burton, Michael. 1972. “Semantic Dimensions of Occupation Names.” Multidimensional Scaling: Applications in the Behavioral Sciences 2: 55–72.

Comment: @amoeba this is what we did, based on your suggestion. Any thoughts?

Comment: @maxheld The first part of this post presents quite a complicated description, and I got a bit lost. Do I understand correctly that you took your binary $35\times 18$ data matrix, interpreted 35 rows as samples and 18 columns as variables, performed PCA on the correlation matrix (center=true, scale=true) and plotted 2 first PCs? What's the point of manual centering (computing "surprise") if you later do PCA that centers by default? If I understood correctly, then your writeup is a huge overcomplication.

Comment: @amoeba sorry for being unclear again. No, we interpreted the 35 rows as *variables* and the 18 columns as *observations*, hence the `t()` in `cor(t(surprise))`. This is a bit stupid on our part, and easily overlooked – we just wanted to start from the same raw data, hence the transposing business.
Anyway, we *manually* first center by *observations*, which isn't usually done, I think, but made sense to us b/c a `TRUE` on a very "rare" category is more meaningful, etc.
We then automatically *center again* on the *variables* (items) in `prcomp()`.

Comment: We do the latter bit (centering on the *variables* aka *items*), because in calculating the $35 Item \times 35 Item$ correlation matrix, we *don't* want the items to have different weight based on their sd and mean. (I understand this actually applies only to the sd, not the mean, but we scaled *and* centered, just to be sure).
Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you center both rows and columns. Just for the reference, this is called *double-centering*. Anyway, good luck with your research!

Answer (score 2):

I have a few approaches which might work for you.

[**k-mediods clustering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)

```
d <- sqrt(1-Azra)
library(cluster)
p2m <- pam(d, 3, dist = TRUE)
plot(p2m)
```

[image]

However, this doesn't seem to return good results for the example you provided. A value of one is ideal.

[**Hierarchical Clustering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering)

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
```

[image]

In my opinion you still get multi-dimensional clustering because Category A can combine with another item or cluster at a higher level if it is the closest item to that cluster during that iteration.

You might also want to refer to this:
[Clustering with a distance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix)

My only concern is the validity of calculating the distance matrix from this data using the method you provided. I don't have a better idea at the moment.

Comment: thanks so much – we're going to implement each of those and try and substantively interpret them.

Comment: I'm still confused about the "multidimensionality" of hierarchical clustering and its adequacy here, but that might very well because I'm too beholden/used to a PCA-way of doing things.
What you say makes a lot of sense to us: that multidimensionality is (sort of) reflected in the higher-level clusters. This might actually make our interpretation more meaningful.
I still worry about the very hierarchy of the clusters, though, which seems at odds with how the data were generated (very much as multidimensional similarity).
Really like that the clustering takes care of the number of clusters.

Comment: I'm also unhappy about how the distance matrix is calculated; that feels hacky/haphazard, and I found only that [CrossValidated post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix) as a source.

Any thoughts on [affinity propagation clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_propagation) which seems to accept *similarity* matrices directly?

Comment: Haven't looked at affinity propagation yet, but it does look like it might be worth looking into for your use case.

Comment: thanks so much again; we ended up taking @amoeba s comment to heart and your worries about how the distance matrix is calculated.
As a result, we went back to the raw data and came up with a different approach, so now we can use PCA.
Thanks so much, anyway for your generous recommendations.