# clustering: what metrics can be used to measure both intra-class variance and inter-class variance, and what are their complexity?

Tags: clustering, variance

I was considering using the [silhouette score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)), however its complexity is $O(mn^2)$ which can quickly become prohibitive with the size of the dataset.

Comment: Are you asking about some internal clustering validation criteria? If yes, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277. Pay attention to Clalinski-Harabasz, Davies-Bouldin.

Comment: Thank you. Are there references listing the complexity of those different validation metrics (my computational ressources are limited...)?