# Finding Optimal Number of Clusters in Expectation Maximization Algorithm

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I know that there are several methods (Elbow method, silhouette analysis etc) which can help me to find the best number of clusters.

**My questions are:**

- What are the best methods to use in Expectation Maximization (EM) Algorithm?
- Can I use elbow method (as if it were for K-means algorithm) to get the "best" number of clusters, but to use in EM Algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Elbow" or SSwithin criterion is a raw, unnormalized source of more advanced indices such as CH (Calinski-Harabasz) or DB (Davies-Bouldin). Read a brief outline at the bottom in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277) answer

Answer (score 2):

The "elbow" method never works well...

Instead, use any of the other internal measures such as Silhouette, Dunn, CH Index, BIC, AIC, C index, etc. that are *much* better and should also work for EM.

If you really want to stick with the *worst* method (Elbow), you could try to look for an elbow in the score function of EM too. Just as with k-means we'd expect the loglikelihood to improve as you increase the number of clusters. There could be an elbow there too, where the rate of improval slows down.