# Cluster analysis- Caring only about the number of clusters in the data not what they are?

Tags: clustering

I know some analysis exists for calculating k for kmeans or kmediods but they dont seem to be rigrous enough if i only care so much about k not what are in the clusters. Is there a rigorous process/algorithm to estimate number of clusters in my data ?

Comment: Check this intruduction, too https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it's a very well-developed field. The approach for estimating the optimal number of clusters in a data set is called "cluster validity."

See:

N. Speer, C. Spieth, and A. Zell.
Biological cluster validity indices based on the gene ontology.
Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 3646:429--439, 2005.

D. Davies and D. Bouldin.
A cluster separation measure.
IEEE Trans. on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 1(2):224--227, 1979.

J. Dunn.
Well separated clusters and optimal fuzzy partitions.
J. Cybernetics, 4:95--104, 1974.

P. Rousseuw.
Silhouettes: A graphical aid to the interpretation and validation of
  cluster analysis.
Computational and Applied Mathematics, 20:53--65, 1987.

M. Gonzalez~Toledo.
A comparison in cluster validation techniques.
Master's thesis, University of Puerto Rico - Mayaguez Campus, 2005.

N. Bolshakova and F. Azuaje.
Cluster validation techniques for genome expression data.
Signal Process., 83(4):825--833, 2003.

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help me get started.