# Use clusters.stats function from a hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I would like a great help from you. I used the cluster.stats function that is part of the `fpc` package to compare the similarity of two custer solutions using a variety of validation criteria, as you can see in the code. However, I have one question:

Is it possible to know which is the most viable cluster, 2 clusters or 5 clusters? If so, could you explain me better how I can know.

Thank you so much!

Best Regards.

```
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(fpc)


df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                   Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.7, -23.7,-23.7), 
                   Longitude = c(-49.5, -49.6, -49.7, -49.8, -49.6,-49.9), 
                   Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 534, 346)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df1<-df

#clusters
coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 

clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k=2) 
df$cluster <- clusters 

clusters1<-cutree(fit.average, k=5) 
df1$cluster <- clusters1

cluster.stats(d,df$cluster,df1$cluster)

> cluster.stats(d,df$cluster,df1$cluster)

$n
[1] 6

$cluster.number
[1] 2

$cluster.size
[1] 4 2

$min.cluster.size
[1] 2

$noisen
[1] 0

$diameter
[1] 24382.84 10198.63

$average.distance
[1] 16490.01 10198.63

$median.distance
[1] 15050.60 10198.63

$separation
[1] 20397.25 20397.25

$average.toother
[1] 29499.05 29499.05

$separation.matrix
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]     0.00 20397.25
[2,] 20397.25     0.00

$ave.between.matrix
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]     0.00 29499.05
[2,] 29499.05     0.00

$average.between
[1] 29499.05

$average.within
[1] 14392.88

$n.between
[1] 8

$n.within
[1] 7

$max.diameter
[1] 24382.84

$min.separation
[1] 20397.25

$within.cluster.ss
[1] 504967651

$clus.avg.silwidths
        1         2 
0.4268101 0.6465108 

$avg.silwidth
[1] 0.5000437

$g2
NULL

$g3
NULL

$pearsongamma
[1] 0.7547454

$dunn
[1] 0.8365412

$dunn2
[1] 1.788904

$entropy
[1] 0.6365142

$wb.ratio
[1] 0.4879101

$ch
[1] 8.157505

$cwidegap
[1] 15048.01 10198.63

$widestgap
[1] 15048.01

$sindex
[1] 20397.25

$corrected.rand
[1] 0.1509434

$vi
[1] 0.9241962
```

Comment: external clustering criteria you are using cannot help you choose the best number of clusters unless one of the two partitions is ground truth. You should therefore rely on internal clustering criteria instead.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that you mentioned some criteria, but is it necessary to do all of them to find the ideal cluster number? I know there may be a discrepancy if you want to see the ideal cluster number for a cluster that used k-means and another that used hierarchical clustering. But in this case, it's just hierarchical clustering. Thank you again.