# How to compare the peformance of different clusterings without true labels

Tags: clustering, data-mining, model-evaluation, unsupervised-learning

Firstly, I know some scores like silhouette score and Davies–Bouldin score to compare the performance in one clustering method. However, I am not sure how to compare results in different clustering methods.

For example, I can use silhouette results to show which is better when setting the number of cluster in K-means.
However, I cannot say that K-means is better than DBSCAN if the score is higher or lower...
So any advice?

Comment: Internal clustering criteria (most of them) can be freely used to compare results between clustering methods. Read overview https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277.