# Silhouette score: counter-intuitive results

Tags: clustering, k-means

so I was looking back at this tutorial (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) and it struck me that the example with `clusters=4`, the one I would have chosen "visually" was not the one with the highest score. Instead `n_clusters=2` was chosen, something I would not have chosen

[image]
[image]
below the scores (taken verbatim from the tutorial)

```
For n_clusters = 2 The average silhouette_score is : 0.7049787496083262
For n_clusters = 3 The average silhouette_score is : 0.5882004012129721
For n_clusters = 4 The average silhouette_score is : 0.6505186632729437
For n_clusters = 5 The average silhouette_score is : 0.56376469026194
For n_clusters = 6 The average silhouette_score is : 0.4504666294372765
```

what am I missing? what would I need to change to have the option with `clusters=4` be the winning one?

Comment: 1) [Criterion vs eye. If data are interval, clusters are not infrequently discernible visually...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277). 2) There exist 100+ different internal clustering criteria. Silhouette is only one of them. Why not try other? Why not try, say, another _version_ of Silhouette criterion, called "Deviation Silhouette aka Simplified Silhouette"?

Comment: Yes at the end I have been trying a combination of different scores and it's working much better!