# How to identify the clusters in SSE plot?

Tags: clustering, k-means

How to determine the number of clusters from the following plot?

[image]

Comment: It's indecisive, but the elbow method is [quite poor in general](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12189).

Comment: try Calinski-Harabasz instead. Here towards the end https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277 I am citing some popular clustering criteria and their properties.

Comment: I agree that SSE elbow on your pic shows no presence of clusters.