How to compare different clustering approaches of categorical data using different similarity measures?
I am working on a project to cluster a dataset containing categorical features. I have tried applying different clustering algorithms like K-modes and HDBSCAN, each using different distance/similarity measures appropriate for categorical data, such as Hamming distance and Jaccard similarity.
To evaluate the quality of the clusterings and select the optimal number of clusters, I am considering using the silhouette score. My questions are:

Is it valid to calculate the silhouette score using Hamming distance as the distance metric, even though the clustering algorithms may be using other measures internally? Does the choice of distance metric need to match between the clustering algorithm and silhouette score?
When comparing the clusterings produced by different algorithms that use different similarity measures (e.g. K-modes with Hamming, HDBSCAN with Jaccard), should I compute the silhouette score using:

A single consistent distance metric (e.g. always Hamming) across
all algorithms to have an apples-to-apples comparison of the
silhouette scores?
The distance metric corresponding to each clustering algorithm (e.g. Hamming for K-modes silhouette, Jaccard for HDBSCAN silhouette) even though this makes the silhouette scores not directly comparable between algorithms?


Are there any caveats or best practices to be aware of when using silhouette score to evaluate and compare clusterings of categorical data?

Any insights or experiences to share on evaluating categorical data clustering quality would be much appreciated. Thanks!

You may wish to start with a meditation on the topic of internal cluster validity indices https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277

For pt 1. Yes why not. A cluster validity criterion needs not to know how the cluster partition it is testing was obtained. It could be any method to partition, even manual. The criterion selected, however, may be not indifferent to the distance measure. Some criteria expect Euclidean distances. Fortunately, Hamming is simply the squared Eucl. d, so almost any criterion will accept it.

thank you for the comment @ttnphns , but as far as i understand it, Hamming distance is only equivalent to the squared Eucl. distance in the case of a binary vector, which would be used for the HDBSCAN (one-hot encoded categorical data) but for k-modes one uses the non encoded categorical data. This makes it even harder to compare the results i think, but I get your point. Maybe to compare the performance one could compare both, silhouette score based on the one-hot encoded data and based on hamming distance for the categorical data.

I would not recommend to use Silhouette criterion with categorical data at all, even recoded into a set of one-hot dummies.

Yes, I also reached the same conclusion. That's why I will also consider different metrics, as described in the article Evaluation of Categorical Data Clustering where the authors suggest, for example, normalized within-cluster variability..
Do you have other ideas instead?

Good. If you have a pdf of this article, could you share it with me? (ttnphns gmail)

For categorical data clustering, I customarily use Ratkowsky-Lance or AIC or BIC for the internal validation.
