calculation of the C-index clustering
Can anyone give me an example of working on the C-index clustering validity test, but calculating manually??

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to the site.  While it may seem unfair, [stats.SE]
is an exclusively English language based site.  All posts
here need to be made in English.  Since
you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which
has information for new users.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English.

See Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange? . . . Briefly, the answer is yes, unless it's on a SE site intended to discuss another language or specifically intended to be in another language.

This seems like it would be a totally on-topic question once it is translated.

Internal cluster validity C-index and its formula and properties you can find on my web-page in collection "Internal clustering criteria".

Check this as well https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277

@ttnphns So now we have to vote to reopen and then vote to close as a duplicate?
