# Cubic clustering criterion in R

Tags: r, clustering

Does anybody know if any package calculates the cubic clustering criterion (CCC) index in R to aid the selection of optimal number of clusters?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but the command `cluster.stats` from the R package [fpc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/fpc.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @Procrastinator Please, make this an answer; this sounds like a good advice, according to the author of the `fpc` package on [R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/05/26324.html). I also gave some pointers on [related](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3692/930) [threads](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11702/930).

Comment: @chl Thanks for your comment. I have to admit that I do not know the area enough to make a defensible answer. I based my comment on the link you posted, the description on the manual and a quick search.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding an R package.

Comment: you could ask them to move it to stack-overflow and they could do good.  The answer already exists and is useful here, showing that the venn diagrams of the subject areas in practice have overlap while in theory they do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is included in `NbClust` and to be used via the option `index = "ccc"`, e. g.

```
I_ccc <- NbClust(X, distance="euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=8, method = "complete",
        index = "ccc")
```