# Cubic Clustering Criterion using R update

Tags: r, clustering

I have seen other users ask about recreating SAS's CCC output in other programs. This question, [Cubic clustering criterion in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29114/cubic-clustering-criterion-in-r), has an answer that says to use `NbClust` to calculate, but that function does not handle large datasets well. It makes a call to `dist` that must allocate a 50 gig object. I have tried replacing the function with `cluster::daisy`, and `proxy::dist` from this SO question with the same memory problems.

Avoiding the `dist` call altogether may be the best option. I am looking to other options to recreate it. In this question [How to define number of clusters in K-means clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/how-to-define-number-of-clusters-in-k-means-clustering/9019#9019), a user goes through the math provided by SAS. But I do not have the stats chops to translate that into R code.

Keeping it simple, I have `kmeans` output that provides total sum of squares (tot.ss), within.ss, between.ss, and I also calculated the $R^2$.

```
kmeans(x = mydata, centers = 23, iter.max = ITER)
Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
 [1]  91248.77  72122.06  78680.32  90402.25  86341.35 153533.51  73988.63  64903.32
 [9]  38334.98  84125.14  92366.93  74721.24 110313.76  96859.55  84516.37  56068.08
[17]  76201.69  86194.35  59526.00  53709.75  72503.21  50767.36  80531.94
 (between_SS / total_SS =  36.5 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"   
[7] "size"         "iter"         "ifault"
```

***Can I calculate the CCC using these measures?***

---

The second question has a long description from the SAS pdf. But I saw a [simplified equation here](http://www.palgrave-journals.com/jibs/journal/v37/n4/fig_tab/8400206t2.html).

[image]

where $E(R^2)$ is the expected $R^2$, and $R^2$ is the observed $R^2$, and $K$ is the variance-stabilizing transformation.

*Can this equation be completed by R's `kmeans` output and a calculated $R^2$

***Edit***

One reason why I am focusing on `kmeans` is that SAS users utilize `PROC FASTCLUS` when running large datasets. It is equivalent to R's kmeans function. The package `NbClust` calculates the CCC that I'm looking for, but it does it on the full data with euclidean distance, which is impossible for most computers. That is equivalent to SAS's `PROC CLUSTER`.

Comment: The CCC is a comparison of how much better the clustering is than a uniform random.  If you had a decent first estimator of kernel bandwidth, then you could use a kernel method to tell you "where your data is".  Also called a "nonparametric density".  You could restrict your uniform sampling to those regions if you use a threshold. (0.001 aka 0.1%?)  It might require a stronger signal to show, but might also work against things like "the curse of dimensionality".

Comment: Can you say that in English? : ) Is the kernel bandwidth and uniform sampling thresholds in the R output or input parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution I chose is to rewrite and extract what `NbClust` was doing but to exclude the `dist` matrix call and everything else that I did not need. I check my custom `CCC` function against the actual output to be sure that the output is the same:

```
> NbClust(iris[-5], min.nc=3, max.nc=3, index="ccc", method="kmeans")
$All.index
[1] 37.6701

$Best.nc
Number_clusters     Value_Index 
         3.0000         37.6701 


> CCC(iris[-5], 3)
[1] 37.67012
```

The measures are the same.

Here's the full function for anyone else interested in `CCC` in R.

*As some may notice, this function also calculates other disgnostics like `c("scott", "rubin", "marriot", "friedman")`. I only needed the CCC for my purposes but the others can also be extracted:*

```
CCC <- function(data, nc) {
  Indices.WBT <- function(x,cl,P,s,vv) 
{
  n <- dim(x)[1]
  pp <- dim(x)[2]
  qq <- max(cl)
  z <- matrix(0,ncol=qq,nrow=n)
  clX <- as.matrix(cl)

  for (i in 1:n)
    for (j in 1:qq)
    {
      z[i,j]==0
      if (clX[i,1]==j) 
      {z[i,j]=1}
    }

  xbar <- solve(t(z)%*%z)%*%t(z)%*%x
  B <- t(xbar)%*%t(z)%*%z%*%xbar
  W <- P-B
  marriot <- (qq^2)*det(W)
  trcovw <- sum(diag(cov(W)))
  tracew <- sum(diag(W))
  if(det(W)!=0)
    scott <- n*log(det(P)/det(W))
  else {cat("Error: division by zero!")}
  friedman <- sum(diag(solve(W)*B))
  rubin <- sum(diag(P))/sum(diag(W))


  R2 <- 1-sum(diag(W))/sum(diag(P))
  v1 <- 1
  u <- rep(0,pp)
  c <- (vv/(qq))^(1/pp)
  u <- s/c
  k1 <- sum((u>=1)==TRUE)
  p1 <- min(k1,qq-1)
  if (all(p1>0,p1<pp))
  {
    for (i in 1:p1)
      v1 <- v1*s[i]
    c <- (v1/(qq))^(1/p1)
    u <- s/c
    b1 <- sum(1/(n+u[1:p1]))
    b2 <- sum(u[p1+1:pp]^2/(n+u[p1+1:pp]),na.rm=TRUE)
    E_R2 <- 1-((b1+b2)/sum(u^2))*((n-qq)^2/n)*(1+4/n)
    ccc <- log((1-E_R2)/(1-R2))*(sqrt(n*p1/2)/((0.001+E_R2)^1.2))
  }else 
  {
    b1 <- sum(1/(n+u))
    E_R2 <- 1-(b1/sum(u^2))*((n-qq)^2/n)*(1+4/n)
    ccc <- log((1-E_R2)/(1-R2))*(sqrt(n*pp/2)/((0.001+E_R2)^1.2))
  }
  results <- list(ccc=ccc,scott=scott,marriot=marriot,trcovw=trcovw,tracew=tracew,friedman=friedman,rubin=rubin)
  return(results)
}


nc <- nc
jeu1 <- as.matrix(data)
numberObsBefore <- dim(jeu1)[1]
jeu <- na.omit(jeu1) # returns the object with incomplete cases removed 
nn <- numberObsAfter <- dim(jeu)[1]
pp <- dim(jeu)[2]    
TT <- t(jeu)%*%jeu   
sizeEigenTT <- length(eigen(TT)$value)
eigenValues <- eigen(TT/(nn-1))$value 

for (i in 1:sizeEigenTT) 
{
  if (eigenValues[i] < 0) {
    #cat(paste("There are only", numberObsAfter,"nonmissing observations out of a possible", numberObsBefore ,"observations."))
    stop("The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated.")
  } 
}
s1 <- sqrt(eigenValues)
ss <- rep(1,sizeEigenTT)
for (i in 1:sizeEigenTT) 
{
  if (s1[i]!=0) 
    ss[i]=s1[i]
}
vv <- prod(ss)  

set.seed(1)  
cl1 <- kmeans(jeu,nc)$cluster
TT <- t(jeu)%*%jeu 
Indices.WBT(x=jeu, cl=cl1, P=TT,s=ss,vv=vv)$ccc
}
```