# How to use both binary and continuous variables together in clustering?

Tags: r, clustering, binary-data, k-means, mixed-type-data

I need to use binary variables (values 0 & 1) in k-means. But k-means only works with continuous variables. I know some people still use these binary variables in k-means ignoring the fact that k-means is only designed for continuous variables. This is unacceptable to me.

Questions:

1. So what is the statistically / mathematically correct way of using binary variables in k-means / hierarchical clustering?
2. How to implement the solution in SAS / R?

Comment: I am curious about the source of your information that "K means is only designed for continuous variables."  Would you be able to cite a reference?

Comment: http://www.jmp.com/support/help/K-Means_Clustering.shtml               "K-Means clustering only supports numeric columns. K-Means clustering ignores model types (nominal and ordinal), and treat all numeric columns as continuous columns."  I just googled and got this. The point is mean is defined for continuous variables not for binary, so k means cannot use binary variables.

Comment: It can use them, by treating them as continuous; but interpreting the result will be hard, because the cluster centers will not have a binary value anymore; and IMHO it is all but clear if the result is too meaningful - why does minimizing variance of a binary variable make sense? Instead, consider e.g. freuqent itemset mining on binary variables if they correspond to present/absent to discover patterns in your data.

Comment: Is there anything more you need, beyond the answers below? This has been around for a long time, & is highly viewed & upvoted, but it isn't clear that your question has been resolved to your satisfaction, & there's also no indication of what you might still be missing.

Answer (score 40):

You are right that k-means clustering should not be done with data of mixed types.  Since k-means is essentially a simple search algorithm to find a partition that minimizes the within-cluster squared Euclidean distances between the clustered observations and the cluster centroid, it should only be used with data where squared Euclidean distances would be meaningful.

When your data consist of variables of mixed types, you need to use Gower's distance.  CV user @ttnphns has a great overview of Gower's distance [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/).  In essence, you compute a distance matrix for your rows for each variable in turn, using a type of distance that is appropriate for that type of variable (e.g., Euclidean for continuous data, etc.); the final distance of row $i$ to $i'$ is the (possibly weighted) average of the distances for each variable.  One thing to be aware of is that Gower's distance isn't actually a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).  Nonetheless, with mixed data, Gower's distance is largely the only game in town.

At this point, you can use any clustering method that can operate over a distance matrix instead of needing the original data matrix.  (Note that k-means needs the latter.)  The most popular choices are [partitioning around medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) (PAM, which is essentially the same as k-means, but uses the most central observation rather than the centroid), various [hierarchical clustering approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria) (e.g., median, single-linkage, and complete-linkage; with hierarchical clustering you will need to decide where to '[cut the tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3685/)' to get the final cluster assignments), and [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) which allows much more flexible cluster shapes.

Here is a simple `R` demo (n.b., there are actually 3 clusters, but the data mostly look like 2 clusters are appropriate):

```
library(cluster)  # we'll use these packages
library(fpc)

  # here we're generating 45 data in 3 clusters:
set.seed(3296)    # this makes the example exactly reproducible
n      = 15
cont   = c(rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1),
           rnorm(n, mean=1, sd=1),
           rnorm(n, mean=2, sd=1) )
bin    = c(rbinom(n, size=1, prob=.2),
           rbinom(n, size=1, prob=.5),
           rbinom(n, size=1, prob=.8) )
ord    = c(rbinom(n, size=5, prob=.2),
           rbinom(n, size=5, prob=.5),
           rbinom(n, size=5, prob=.8) )
data   = data.frame(cont=cont, bin=bin, ord=factor(ord, ordered=TRUE))
  # this returns the distance matrix with Gower's distance:  
g.dist = daisy(data, metric="gower", type=list(symm=2))
```

We can start by searching over different numbers of clusters with PAM:

```
  # we can start by searching over different numbers of clusters with PAM:
pc = pamk(g.dist, krange=1:5, criterion="asw")
pc[2:3]
# $nc
# [1] 2                 # 2 clusters maximize the average silhouette width
# 
# $crit
# [1] 0.0000000 0.6227580 0.5593053 0.5011497 0.4294626
pc = pc$pamobject;  pc  # this is the optimal PAM clustering
# Medoids:
#      ID       
# [1,] "29" "29"
# [2,] "33" "33"
# Clustering vector:
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
#  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  2 
# 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
#  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2 
# Objective function:
#     build      swap 
# 0.1500934 0.1461762 
# 
# Available components:
# [1] "medoids"    "id.med"     "clustering" "objective"  "isolation" 
# [6] "clusinfo"   "silinfo"    "diss"       "call"
```

Those results can be compared to the results of hierarchical clustering:

```
hc.m = hclust(g.dist, method="median")
hc.s = hclust(g.dist, method="single")
hc.c = hclust(g.dist, method="complete")
windows(height=3.5, width=9)
  layout(matrix(1:3, nrow=1))
  plot(hc.m)
  plot(hc.s)
  plot(hc.c)
```

[image]

The median method suggests 2 (possibly 3) clusters, the single only supports 2, but the complete method could suggest 2, 3 or 4 to my eye.

Finally, we can try DBSCAN.  This requires specifying two parameters: eps, the 'reachability distance' (how close two observations have to be to be linked together) and minPts (the minimum number of points that need to be connected to each other before you are willing to call them a 'cluster').  A rule of thumb for minPts is to use one more than the number of dimensions (in our case 3+1=4), but having a number that's too small isn't recommended.  The default value for `dbscan` is 5; we'll stick with that.  One way to think about the reachability distance is to see what percent of the distances are less than any given value.  We can do that by examining the distribution of the distances:

```
windows()
  layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
  plot(density(na.omit(g.dist[upper.tri(g.dist)])), main="kernel density")
  plot(ecdf(g.dist[upper.tri(g.dist)]), main="ECDF")
```

[image]

The distances themselves seem to cluster into visually discernible groups of 'nearer' and 'further away'.  A value of .3 seems to most cleanly distinguish between the two groups of distances.  To explore the sensitivity of the output to different choices of eps, we can try .2 and .4 as well:

```
dbc3 = dbscan(g.dist, eps=.3, MinPts=5, method="dist");  dbc3
# dbscan Pts=45 MinPts=5 eps=0.3
#        1  2
# seed  22 23
# total 22 23
dbc2 = dbscan(g.dist, eps=.2, MinPts=5, method="dist");  dbc2
# dbscan Pts=45 MinPts=5 eps=0.2
#         1  2
# border  2  1
# seed   20 22
# total  22 23
dbc4 = dbscan(g.dist, eps=.4, MinPts=5, method="dist");  dbc4
# dbscan Pts=45 MinPts=5 eps=0.4
#        1
# seed  45
# total 45
```

Using `eps=.3` does give a very clean solution, which (qualitatively at least) agrees with what we saw from other methods above.

Since there is no meaningful *cluster 1-ness*, we should be careful of trying to match which observations are called 'cluster 1' from different clusterings.  Instead, we can form tables and if most of the observations called 'cluster 1' in one fit are called 'cluster 2' in another, we would see that the results are still substantively similar.  In our case, the different clusterings are mostly very stable and put the same observations in the same clusters each time; only the complete linkage hierarchical clustering differs:

```
  # comparing the clusterings
table(cutree(hc.m, k=2), cutree(hc.s, k=2))
#    1  2
# 1 22  0
# 2  0 23
table(cutree(hc.m, k=2), pc$clustering)
#    1  2
# 1 22  0
# 2  0 23
table(pc$clustering, dbc3$cluster)
#    1  2
# 1 22  0
# 2  0 23
table(cutree(hc.m, k=2), cutree(hc.c, k=2))
#    1  2
# 1 14  8
# 2  7 16
```

Of course, there is no guarantee that any cluster analysis will recover the true latent clusters in your data.  The absence of the true cluster labels (which would be available in, say, a logistic regression situation) means that an enormous amount of information is unavailable.  Even with very large datasets, the clusters may not be sufficiently well separated to be perfectly recoverable.  In our case, since we know the true cluster membership, we can compare that to the output to see how well it did.  As I noted above, there are actually 3 latent clusters, but the data give the appearance of 2 clusters instead:

```
pc$clustering[1:15]    # these were actually cluster 1 in the data generating process
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
# 1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1 
pc$clustering[16:30]   # these were actually cluster 2 in the data generating process
# 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
#  2  2  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  1  2 
pc$clustering[31:45]   # these were actually cluster 3 in the data generating process
# 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
#  2  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Comment: at hierarchical clustering plotting you mention `median method suggests 2 (possibly 3) clusters, the single only supports 2, but the complete method could suggest 2, 3 or 4`.. how do you arrive at this? using a height of 0.3?

Comment: @lukeg, the heights of the joins on the dendrogram represent how far you have to go to merge 2 clusters. You are looking for where distances become further to continue agglomerating. It might help to read the threads that discuss this [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3685/) &/or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2597/).

Answer (score 4):

Look at this paper by Finch, http://www.jds-online.com/files/JDS-192.pdf.  It describes both why applying continuous methods to binary data may inaccurately cluster the data, and more importantly what are some choices in appropriate distance functions.  It does not answer how to cluster with k-means, but rather how to properly cluster binary data using non-Euclidean metrics and a hierarchical method like Ward.